# Is there a way to know when an echoSign document has been successfully signed in real time?

Tags: echosign

I'm still new at echoSign API and still at learning phase. I hit some roadblocks so I'm seeking for help.

So I have a form, with a echosign document. Its actually an echosign widget. With the script(below) attached to the form document body.

`<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://secure.echosign.com/public/embeddedWidget?wid={widgetID}'></script>`

Is there a way that this particular widget could throw an event if they successfully signed the widget ( using the current user session ). I'm not sure if thats possible.

I know it could retrieve information's from the API using `GET /widgets/{widgetId}/agreements`. But is there a way that the form knows the event real time?

Thanks for the help in advance. Looking forward.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are asking is a callback mechanism that will alert your system whenever an agreement is created out of a widget.
During creation of widget through API you can specify callBackInfo which is basically a URl where echosign will ping your system will the final signed copy.

Here is the detailed description of this request parameter -

**callbackInfo (string, optional): A publicly accessible url to which Adobe Sign will do an HTTP GET operation every time there is a new agreement event. HTTP authentication is supported using standard embedded syntax - i.e. http://username:password@your.server.com/path/to/file. Adobe Sign can also ping your system using HTTP PUT with the final signed PDF. Please contact**

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AdobeSign and I uses the callbackInfo to get real time events.

The callback returns the widgetId, the agreement Id tied to it and the status of the widget. Here are the status im getting so far: WIDGET_WAITING_FOR_VERIFICATION, OUT_FOR_SIGNATURE and SIGNED.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an ancient question. But I ran into the same issue, and I found this question sooner than the correct documentation: https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/sign/docs/events.html

If you have an iframe with the widget, you would add an event listener to the MessageEvent on the parent window:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    if (e.origin == "https://secure.echosign.com") {
        console.log("Event from Adobe Sign!", JSON.parse(e.data)); 
    }else {
        console.log("Do not process this!");
    }
}

window.addEventListener('message', eventHandler);
```